# Cómo calcular el promedio de unos valores que se dan por teclado y que finaliza cuando introduces 0

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa que calcule el promedio de todos los valores que introduzcas por teclado, y que éste finalice cuando introduces el número 0.

He intentado realizarlo de diferentes maneras. Lo más cercano que he llegado para la solución lo reflejo en el código siguiente.

Ejecuto el programa e introduzco los números 2, 3 y 4 (Sin contar el 0 que es lo que uso para terminar el programa ), y me da la siguiente solución que es errónea:

> Introduzca el primer número: 2 Introduzca otro número: 3 Introduzca
>   otro número: 4 Introduzca otro número: 0 (La suma es 7) (El número de
>   elementos son 3) (El promedio es 2)

Espero que me podáis ayudar, muchas gracias a todos :).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio4_ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x;
        int contador=1;
        int suma=0;


        Scanner entrada=new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduzca el primer número");
        x=entrada.nextInt();

        do {

            System.out.println("Introduzca otro número");
            x=entrada.nextInt();
            contador++;
            suma=x+suma;



            if (x==0) {

                contador--;
                int promedio=0;
                promedio=suma/contador;
                System.out.println("La suma es " + suma);
                System.out.println("El número de elementos son " + contador);
                System.out.println("El promedio es " + promedio);


            }

        }while(x!=0);

    }

}
```

Comment: Depura tu programa y te darás cuenta del problema. El primer dato lo pides pero no lo sumas, fuera del bucle, y luego en el bucle sí. En cada vuelta del bucle vas sumando números y contándo cuantos llevas. El bucle termina al pulsar cero y fuera del bucle es cuando deberías hacer la media, cuando ya has terminado de pedir los datos y ya tienes la suma total.

Comment: Tienes razón, muchas gracias por la respuesta :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en el bucle. No tienes en cuenta el primer elemento. Además no tratas el escenario de que obtengas 0 como el primer número. A mi en particular me gusta más utilizar el bucle **while** en vez del **do-while**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x;
    int contador=0;
    int suma=0;

    Scanner entrada=new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduzca el primer número");
    x = entrada.nextInt();

    while(x != 0){
      suma += x;
      contador ++;
      System.out.println("Introduzca otro número");
      x = entrada.nextInt();     
    }

    if (contador == 0){
      // Lo que quieres que pase si el primer número es 0
      System.out.println("El primer valor introducido es 0");
    }else {
      int promedio = suma / contador;
      System.out.println("La suma es " + suma);
      System.out.println("El número de elementos son " + contador);
      System.out.println("El promedio es " + promedio);
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Tu código me ha ayudado mucho a entender mejor lo que estaba haciendo mal.

Comment: De nada. Recuerda votar si te ha sido de ayuda tanto los comentarios como las respuestas que recibas en esta y futuras preguntas. Échale un vistazo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote